# JUnit categories with multi module project - Unable to load category

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, testing, junit4

I want to include/exclude JUnit categorized tests. I have a marker interface `StressTest` defined in a common module. I am referencing `StressTest` in moduleA. I have the following maven-surefire-plugin in root `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.20</version>
<configuration>
  <excludedGroups>com.mycompany.project.common.utils.StressTest</excludedGroups>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

When running mvn test I get the following while building another module.

```
Unable to load category: com.mycompany.project.common.utils.StressTest
```

Where should I write my `StressTest` interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for surefire to 'find' your `@Category` class it must be on the classpath produced from your Maven project's dependency tree.

This exception ...

> Unable to load category: com.mycompany.project.common.utils.StressTest

... strongly implies that whatever artifact contains `com.mycompany.project.common.utils.StressTest` is **not** a declared dependency of your `moduleA`.

So, you'll need to add a dependency on whatever artifact contains `com.mycompany.project.common.utils.StressTest` to your `moduleA`. If the only purpose of this dependency is to provide the `@Category` class then it would make sense to make this dependency test scoped e.g.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>common.utils</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Furthermore, if `com.mycompany.project.common.utils.StressTest` is in the **test** tree rather than the **main** tree in your common utils module then you will need to create a JAR containing the common utils module's test classes. You can do this by adding the following `maven-jar-plugin` declaration to the common utils' pom.xml:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>test-jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

You would then depend on this using `<type>test-jar</type>`in the dependency in your `moduleA`, for example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>common.utils</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If I define StressTest under test/java then it doesn't work but if I define it in main/java then it works.

Comment: @bluetech I have updated the answer to describe how to export and depend on a `test-jar` from your common utils module.